# Create ros package

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-16.04, ros, point-cloud-library

I am trying to follow [this site.](http://ros-developer.com/2017/05/15/object-recognition-and-6dof-pose-estimation-with-pcl-pointcloud-and-ros/)

I want to realize this source on rviz.

I have done the following.

1. Created a ROS package

`catkin_create_pkg pkg_name roscpp`

2. Created CMakeList
3. Inserted source file

   `pkg_name/src/sorce.cpp`
4. `catkin_make`

`~/pkg_name$ catkin_make`

Then, I got the following error

`The specified base path "/home/usr/pkg_name" contains a package but "catkin_make" must be invoked in the root of workspace`

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first create a workspace. Follow [this link](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace). Then inside your workspace's src folder, you can create your package following [this link](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage). These are links to ROS Wiki tutorials which you should go through if you are new to ROS.